# How might I generate a list of unique words present within a Microsoft Word document, preserving hyphenated entries

Tags: vba, ms-word, extract, document

Would like to generate a list of unique words present within a Microsoft Word document, using the below VBA code. However, the document in question contains many hyphenated entries that must be preserved in the resultant list. Please advise on how the code may be modified to accommodate those words immediately beginning, ending, and containing one or more hyphens. Other punctuations shall remain omitted, as they are by the present code. Relevant extractions include: **ad-** , **-banner** , **tack-weld** , **well-to-do**, and the like. Words will include accented characters, and those characters must be retained as would a-z.

```
Sub UniqueWordList()
    Dim wList As New Collection
    Dim wrd
    Dim chkwrd
    Dim sTemp As String
    Dim k As Long

    For Each wrd In ActiveDocument.Range.Words
        sTemp = Trim(LCase(wrd))
        If sTemp >= "a" And sTemp <= "z" Then
            k = 0
            For Each chkwrd In wList
                k = k + 1
                If chkwrd = sTemp Then GoTo nw
                If chkwrd > sTemp Then
                    wList.Add Item:=sTemp, Before:=k
                    GoTo nw
                End If
            Next chkwrd
            wList.Add Item:=sTemp
        End If
nw:
    Next wrd

    sTemp = "There are " & ActiveDocument.Range.Words.Count & " words "
    sTemp = sTemp & "in the document, before this summary, but there "
    sTemp = sTemp & "are only " & wList.Count & " unique words."

    ActiveDocument.Range.Select
    Selection.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
    Selection.TypeText vbCrLf & sTemp & vbCrLf
    For Each chkwrd In wList
        Selection.TypeText chkwrd & vbCrLf
    Next chkwrd
End Sub
```

Comment: See, for example: https://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/11875-how-can-i-count-multiple-usage-same.html

Answer (score 0):

Read up on arraylist , specifically the .Contains method (or just use the Keys of a Scripting.Dictionary with the .Exists method).  Work through the document by paragraph .  Split the text for each paragraph at the spaces. Write a function that removes unwanted characters from each end of the word.